# Laravel catch-all routes

Tags: laravel, routes

I looking-for solution to make all routes more readable and shorter.

It's any good solution for routes to make it like below:

```
localhost/{cityNameSlug}
localhost/{companyNameSlug}
localhost/{subPageSlug}
```

instead of:

```
localhost/cities/{cityNameSlug}
localhost/companies/{companyNameSlug}
localhost/pages/{subPageSlug}
```

City name slugs or/and company name slugs could be stored in Cache or something similar.

Of course we use CitiesController, CompaniesController and PagesController.

Comment: You can't have multiple routes with the same signature, at least with just the routes file. There's no way for Laravel to know if it's a cityNameSlug, companyNameSlug, or subPageSlug. You can have 1 route to match all 3, and then use logic in the controller to determine if it's city, company, or subPage. You'll just need to make sure that a slug is unique among all 3, either by checking each table individually, or creating a table for all the slugs and the type of slug it is.

Comment: You can use this to catch all routes.

```Route::get('{any}', function ($any) {
        ...
    })->where('any', '.*');```

Of course you will have to write a logic to distinguish between different types of slug

Comment: The 2nd set of Routes is how I usually approach this. There is always a chance you will have a Slug that exists in more than 1 of those 3 types, and if you do `localhost/whatever`, how would your code know which Controller to use? aynber suggests a couple approaches, but both have drawbacks in either performance (checking multiple tables, and handling what to do if you find the slug in multiple) or setup/maintenance (storing the slugs in a single table and associating them with 3 other tables, and you'd still need to handle duplicates). Adding `/city` (or `company`, etc) before the slug is 